# How to modify (monkey-patching) third-party function at specific line

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

I'm wonder is it possible to modify third-party function (like monkey-patching [[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)], [[nice article](http://me.dt.in.th/page/JavaScript-override/)]) in a way to add some few lines in the middle of those functions?

Example of what I want:

Third-party (patching target):

```
var obj = {
  sum: function (a) {
    var b = 1;
    //Here I want to add a line:
    // b = 2
    return a + b;
  }
};
```

N.B.: I know that we can execute custom functions **before** and **after** a original function call, but I want to execute custom code **in the middle** of the original function's body.

**UPD**: I'll share my thoughts below as an answer, but it's ugly so I want to find any other ways.

Comment: You can simply replace the *sum* function if you want: `obj.sum = function(){/*your stuff*/};`.

Comment: @RobG Yep, thanks, it's much easier but not applicable for some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit ugly way to do that. I didn't test it well, but it's should work:

```
    // Split function into array of strings
    var arr = obj.sum.toString().split('\n');
    // Insert our expression (b = 2) at "line 2"
    arr.splice(2, 0, "b = 2");
    // Remove first line: "function (a) {" (to be honest we should first parse and remember args)
    arr.splice(0, 1)
    //Remove last line: "}"
    arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1)
    // Create a string with our function
    var str  = arr.join("\n")
    //Create function with new Function()
    var newFunc = new Function("a", str); //a -is our argument for "sum" func
    obj.sum = newFunc;
```